# How do you properly align refference images

Tags: modeling, image

Hello everyone im quite new to blender and i have been trying to model a car for quite some time now. I have looked everywhere and didnt find an answer to my question so here it is. Every time i align thing on 2 views the 3rd is WAY off. Images are all the same scale properly aligned using the blender coordinate system(i think). How can i fix this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

edit: Here is the file
[image]

Comment: could you please show a screenshot to illustrate your problem?

Comment: [views](https://imgur.com/a/yKz36pj) here are the views

Comment: hard to see where is the problem, maybe pack your image (File > External Data > Pack All Into .blend), save and share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I think good models are rarely made using only 3 drawings. Finding good reference data for modelling is often harder than modelling itself. I would recommend finding the car model and taking photographs for reference yourself. Using long focal length lens to minimize perspective distortion. You would just look at them and see if the proportions in the drawings are correct. In reality, if I had an order to model a specific car I would even use photogrammetry to make my life easier, because why not?.. Unless it's a rare expensive car and I cannot find any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really seems like the blueprints aren't very precise, as [moonboots](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/34531/moonboots) already mentioned.

Look:
[image: bp]

I've used basic geometry as a guide and marked just two regions which should line up, but don't. The lower right part of the hood (where your active vertex resides) is clearly to high in front view (marked yellow).

In general, it is good practice to evaluate blueprints by doing this before you start.

Here are some rough steps to follow.

1. Research real world dimensions of your vehicle.
2. Create a simple box with those dimensions as reference.
3. Place the blueprints inside the box and make sure they match exactly on the bounds. (Roof, tires, side mirrors, trunk, front)
4. Check prominent features for alignment. I.e. by using more basic geometry.

That way, you can be aware of any issues right from the start.

--

Blueprints are very often not exact and it won't be possible to place geometry perfectly in all views.
When that happens, you can for example stick to those views that match and work with a bit of offset on the one that doesn't match. Or you can go half way.
Just maintain the shape / curvature of the misaligned view as a reference.

And you should always find good real world reference images to decide on how to proceed with areas where the blueprints are off or don't show enough detail.

--

So, as far as I can see from your blendfile, you've done nothing wrong with the blueprints.

Answer (score 2):

So I think you just need to select this part:

[image]

move it up:

[image]

and it looks like you're good?

[image]

[image]

Comment: i know that but i mean the verticies are off when i align them on 1 view they dont aling on the other. the hood specifically look at it from the right view it is off by a lot. how do i fix that ?

Comment: maybe it's because your blueprint is not 100% perfect, please show a precise example (one vertex that doesn't match)

Comment: it happens to every blueprint i try i must be doing something wrong here

Comment: you need to go on, your roof is a bit curvy so you need to bevel front and rear, then you'll see if it still doesn't match, there may be some slight differences, it depends on the blueprint accuracy I guess